# Probability of a particular finite combination of heads and tails in infinite tosses sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am asked to find the probability of getting HHHTHHTT or (111010011) combination in infinite coin tosses sequence where probability of getting heads is $p$.

So I thought that if it starts with the first toss it would be simply $p^3(p-1)p^2(p-1)^2=p^5(p-1)^3$. But it does not need to start with the first toss, so what then? How to take this into consideration?

Comment: Well, the probability of finding any finite subsequence in an infinite sequence of tosses is 1. It's called [Infinite-Monkey-Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) :) The subsequence itself must be posible though, which ist true in your case.

Comment: A more interesting question would be finding the expected tosses to get this particular sequence.

Comment: @karakfa That can be done by solving the following equations where $p+q=1$ and $\mu$ denotes the expectation: $\begin{aligned}\mu & =1+p\mu_{H}\\
\mu_{H} & =1+p\mu_{HH}+q\mu\\
\mu_{HH} & =1+p\mu_{HHH}+q\mu\\
\mu_{HHH} & =1+p\mu_{HHH}+q\mu_{HHHT}\\
\mu_{HHHT} & =1+p\mu_{HHHTH}+q\mu\\
\mu_{HHHTH} & =1+p\mu_{HHHTHH}+q\mu\\
\mu_{HHHTHH} & =1+p\mu_{HHH}+q\mu_{HHHTHHT}\\
\mu_{HHHTHHT} & =1+p\mu_{H}+q
\end{aligned}
$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the string as concatenation of strings of length $8$ and call these strings the special strings.

The probability that the first special string is not HHHTHHTT is a number $r<1$.

Then the probability that none of the first $n$ special strings is HHHTHHTT is $r^n$.

If $s$ denote the probability that none of the special strings is HHHTHHTT then $s\leq r^n$ for every $n$.

This for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ and $r<1$ so this can only be true if $s=0$.

That means that the probability that at least one of the special strings is HHHTHHTT is $1$.

Then of course the same is true if we look at all strings of length $8$ (not only the special ones).

---

It can also be proved for every integer $n$ that the probability that not more than $n$ strings of length $8$ will be HHHTHHTT is $0$, and from this it follows that the probability that an *infinite number* of strings of length $8$ will be HHHTHHTT equals $1$.